# What is the meaning of volume for an index?

Tags: market-indexes

http://yhoo.it/9K44hN lists the historical price of Dow Jones Industrial index in a table. The 6th column of this table is the volume information. What does the volume listed in this column exactly represent?

For example, consider the following line from this table:

```
Date        | Open      | High      | Low       | Close     | Volume
Sep 2, 2010 | 10,270.08 | 10,350.98 | 10,211.80 | 10,320.10 | 3,704,210,00
```

The last number 3,704,210,000 is the volume information. What does it exactly represent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The volume, in this case, is the total number of shares traded on that index on that specific day.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean the following: the number of shares traded of the companies included in the index?

Comment: Yes, exactly...