# Understanding stock market terminology

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, stock-valuation

I have few months of data for some company like `opening, high, low, closing, volume` .

As given at https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NYSE%3ABME&ei=DSIeVtGMAYrvuATEsZfACA

Can someone please explain me what each value stands for? Is it stock values? and then what is the `volume`?

Also what is

```
{PE}x trailing P/E, a {PS}x P/S ratio and a trailing P/FCF of {MARKETCAP/FCF} 


REVENUEGROWTH1YR current quarter% from REVENUEGROWTH1YR previous quarter

{NETINCGROWTH1YR current quarter}% year-over-year vs. prior quarter’s {NETINCGROWTH1YR previous quarter}% rise
```

Comment: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3392/what-is-the-meaning-of-volume-for-an-index

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Opening - is the price at which the first trade gets executed at the start of the trading day (or trading period).

High - is the highest price the stock is traded at during the day (or trading period).

Low - is the lowest price the stock is traded at during the day (or trading period).

Closing - is the price at which the last trade gets executed at the end of the trading day (or trading period).

Volume - is the amount of shares that get traded during the trading day (or trading period). For example, if you bought 1000 shares during the day and another 9 people also bought 1000 shares each, then the trading volume for the day would be 10 x 1000 = 10,000.

Comment: don't forget that on most exchanges opening and closing are part of the two auctions

Comment: @Victor: thanks, well any idea about other terms I have added

Comment: Price/Earnings  - Price/Sales - Price/Free Cash Flow are the other three. Trailing means it trails the current quarter - not sure how long it trails though since it doesn't mention. The revenue growth are %'s that the revenues have grown that quarter.

Answer (score -1):

One of the most useful ways to depict Open, High, Low, Close, and Volume is with a Candlestick Chart. I like to use the following options from Stockcharts.com:

http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?s=SPY&p=D&yr=0&mn=3&dy=0&id=p57211761385